# Can't run junit tests on Eclipse with Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, java-9

I try to play with Java 9 on *Eclipse Oxygen 4.7*. I have installed *Java 9 Support for Oxygen* from marketplace obviously. I can't get junit test to work. I've created simple maven project with two classes:

- MyClass in src/main/java/testing
- MyClassTest in src/test/java/testing

When I try to run junit test from eclipse I get the exception `Class not found testing.MyClassTest`. I'm assuming that for some reason directory `target/test-classes` is not included into classpath.

If go back to java 1.8 in project settings, then junit test run just fine.

- in Project Settings -> Java Compiler switch JDK compliance to 1.8
- in Project Settings -> Java Build Path change JRE System library to 1.8

What can I do to run this test with Java 9 within Eclipse?

Comment: *Class not found **testing.MyClassTest*** the package name does not resemble the details as shared in the question about the project.... *MyClassTest in src/test/java*

Comment: Same for me, using JUnit 5 and Oxygen.1 with support for Java 9.

Comment: Sample repo which reproduces the issue: https://github.com/heruan/java9-eclipse-junit as `mvn test` runs fine but Eclipse "Run > JUnit" fails.

Comment: About package - I corrected the description.

Answer (score 0):

As you have two separate source (and class folders) it looks like you are running into: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525382

executing the test on the command line using `mvn test` works for me